# Searching in MongoDB with string in any order

Tags: mongodb

I have a name "PIERRE JOHN IGUE" in mongodb, where i need to match the string in any order even if i give like "JOHN PIERRE", "PIERRE IGUE", "JOHN IGUE" , "IGUE PIERRE" in any order i have to find the result, like search will return only the exact matching words. Is there any way to query in mongodb to search string in any order.

Comment: While it's not ready for production use, you might see if an upcoming feature would match your needs. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/search-for-text/ Doing brute-force searches through a collection is not recommended if you care about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Usa a [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in your find

```
{$regex: "PEIRE|JOHN|IGUE", $option: "i" }
```

Comment: That regex wouldn't be an exact match.

Comment: if the name "PEIRE JOHN" is in mongodb and i searched "DEIRE JOHN" then also this "PEIRE JOHN" should be found. since its is similar to that name

Comment: @deepu To explain, the particular match there would find either PEIRE or JOHN or IGUE within the string for the field you are  searching. So this will match documents that have any of those terms. Combination searching is a fair bit more complex, and better reserved for a text search engine if that suits your purposes. Otherwise you can filter results as shown, but it will not be exact.

Comment: @NeilLunn is there any way to get soundex like matching in mongodb